# Execute R script within R project from MAC terminal

Tags: r, bash, macos, rstudio

I have a set of projects in R studio which I open and run a script within them on a daily basis. I want to automate this procedure to save time, by creating a bash script that will open the projects, run the script within them and then close them. I am to the point that I can open a project by running `open project.Rproj` but I have not found how to execute a script once I open the project in some automated manner (using a bash command).
Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: cron and `Rscript` or `r` (from `litter`)?

Comment: @GordonShumway The nominated duplicate is heavily Windows-biased. Reading between the lines a bit, it should not be hard to see how to apply it on Mac. I added another couple of duplicates as well.